# Required fields in the user profile

Tags: field, user-profile, required

how to make required plane text fields or required firsrtName and lastName fields in users profile? I want to during the registration and profile changes were required. Maybe there is any plugin for this?

Answer (score 3):

For custom fields that you add to `users` under `settings>users>fields`, you can control whether the field is required by clicking on the small gear icon and selecting `make required`. With built-in fields such as `firstName` and `lastName`, `make required` cannot be controlled. Within the CP, at least, you would need to look for a plug-in solution.

On the front-end, I would suggest a writting javascript solution that simply validates that the fields are not empty before submitting the form (or before enabling the submit button). Have a look at jquery's [`.on('click')` or `.on('change')`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) functionality for more info.